# Equivalent of /dev/null for writing garbage test data?

Tags: php, garbage, dev-null

I need to perform a series of test for picking the fastest branch of code for a set of functions I designed. As this functions output some text/HTML content, I would like to measure the speed without filling the browser with garbage data.

Is there an equivalent to /dev/null in PHP? The closest equivalent to write temporary data I've found are `php://temp` and `php://memory` but those two I/O streams store the garbage data and I want for every piece of data to be written in a 'fake' fashion.

I could always write all garbage data in a variable ala `$tmp .= <function return value goes here>` but I'm sure there must be a more elegant or a better way to accomplish this **WITHOUT** resorting to functions like `shell_exec()`, `exec()`, `proc_open()` and similar approaches (the production server I'm going to test the final code won't have any of those commands).

Is there an equivalent?

Comment: use output buffering surround the code with `ob_start()` `ob_end_clean()`

Comment: if you dont want output, dont output anything!

Comment: If you seemingly want a file resource for output, why is using `/dev/null` not feasible. How does your code output?

Comment: @Dagon that's not the point. I need to test output speed (among other factors) so I have to output the function return value. Just... I want to do it without (ideally) filling any buffer (my test loops usually iterate over the 10K mark and runs on the 1M mark on average, so filling that much data is not an option... not a sane one, at least) :P

Comment: well if you throw away the output, your not testing it.

Comment: @mario god... for a moment, I felt really stupid... you can actually open a file pointer to `/dev/null`, so my question wasn't formulated well. Thank you very much for the pointer :)

Comment: @Dagon for the test I have in mind right now (and like I said in my question), I need to measure the execution speed so I need to produce the result from a series of functions. Using the results or displaying them is not relevant per se (for this test).

Comment: then back to no output required, your going in cycles here

Comment: If you want to test **output** speed, you should output it to something meaningful, be it TTY, your browser, or a file (all of these are going to have different timings!). If you want to test data **calculation** speed, then you should indeed write to `/dev/null`, which was made for this purpose among others.

Comment: Write to `/tmp` and delete file after your done with test.

Answer (score 1):

// For what its worth, this works on CentOS 6.5 php 5.3.3.

```
$fname = "/dev/null";
if(file_exists($fname))   print "*** /dev/null exists ***\n";

if (is_readable($fname))  print "*** /dev/null readable ***\n";

if (is_writable($fname))  print "*** /dev/null writable ***\n";

if (($fileDesc = fopen($fname, "r"))==TRUE){
    print "*** I opened /dev/null for reading ***\n";
    $x = fgetc($fileDesc);
    fclose($fileDesc);
}

if (($fileDesc = fopen($fname, "w"))==TRUE)
{
    print "*** I opened /dev/null for writing ***\n";
    $x = fwrite($fileDesc,'X');
    fclose($fileDesc);
}
if (($fileDesc = fopen($fname, "w+"))==TRUE) {
    print "*** I opened /dev/null for append ***\n";
    $x = fwrite($fileDesc,'X');
    fclose($fileDesc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be a [streamWrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) that profiles your output on write with microtime, that you can then [stream_wrapper_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) . The [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) in the manual is pretty good.

If your code is not that complicated or you fell this would be overkill, you can just use the [ob_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) callback handler

Hope this helps.